# How can I get html files by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want access html file in "https://www.setgame.com/set/puzzle" by JavaScript but I cannot.

I will show the JavaScript code what I make and the error log.

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest(url) {
  // This is a sample server that supports CORS.

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    alert(xhr.status)

    var text = xhr.responseText;
    alert(text)
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
      alert(xhr.responseText)
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}

makeCorsRequest("https://www.setgame.com/set/puzzle")
```

Chrome shows the following errors.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.setgame.com/set/puzzle' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You can't, unless people who control `www.setgame.com` let you. (Also, `XDomainRequest` is no longer supported.)

Comment: can you be more specific about  want access html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send CORS request successfully, origin server (in this case, setgame.com) must allow CORS request. (With Access-Control-Allow-Origin header)

This means, you can't access CORS-blocked server by browser-side javascript.

Try use node.js (server-sided things)

Comment: I'd rather say "try using serverside" - anything will do, not just node.js.